# Ui programmatically with multilingual

Tags: iphone, ios, multilingual

I am trying to learn how to implement multilingual for an iphone app. I create my ui programmatically always. please check the code as below

```
UIImage *buttonImage2 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"orangebuttonsmall.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:22 topCapHeight:0];
btnCancel = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btnCancel setTitle:@"Save" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnCancel setBackgroundImage:buttonImage2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btnCancel.frame = CGRectMake(205, 40.0, 60.0, 30.0);
btnCancel.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
btnCancel.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
btnCancel.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
btnCancel.titleLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.3]; // [UIColor blackColor];
btnCancel.titleLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, -1);
[btnCancel sizeToFit];
btnCancel.bounds = CGRectInset(btnCancel.bounds, -10, 0);
[btnCancel addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.containerView addSubview:btnCancel];
```

when I search for the localization, I get the examples for xibs but not programmatically.
now I would like to know how can I change the above code to be multi lingual for example French.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[btnCancel setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Save",@"Title for Save Button") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Then use the terminal command

```
genstrings -o en.lproj *.m
```

to generate a Localizable.strings file

Then tailor the resultant Localizable.strings file for each language and store in appropriate Lang.lproj subfolder in your project.  (French.lproj  English.lproj etc.)

The NSLocalizedString function will pull in the language specific value and substitute it in the code.

Comment: couldn't connect to output directory en.lproj when i run the genstrings command. what is the problem here

Comment: mkdir en.lproj before running genstrings

Answer (score 1):

you need to make  your code localized. for more info pls. go through these links   http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/iphone-applications-localization-guide/  or   http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial